# How to rebuild qwt with mingw-64

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, mingw32, qwt

I have a 32bit program compiled with mingw32 which was using qwt built with mingw32 and it is working fine. When i try to compile it using mingw-64 i receive the following errors:

```
:-1: skipping incompatible C:/Qwt-6.1.2/lib\libqwtd.a when searching for -lqwtd
:-1:  cannot find -lqwtd
```

If i understand correctly i should rebuild qwt with 64 bit compiler but i have no idea how to do it.Building it with mingw32 command line which comes with qt was easy, but there is no such thing for mingw64.
So how can i make it work? Oh and btw i got mingw64 compiler by installing Qt64-NG

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i am slow... I just opened qwt's pro file in qt creator and compiled it with 64 bit compiler.